# mCustomScrollbar jQuery plugin with iFrame embedded

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, iframe

I'm hoping you can help!

I am using this plugin http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller which works great. The problem I am finding is that I am embedding youtube/vimeo clips (iFrames) within the scoller, which works fine, except for the fact that the mousewheel scroll doesn't work when the mouse is over the iFrame.

I suppose the javascript scroll event isn't being fired because the browser thinks I am trying to scroll within the iFrame? Is there any way around this? Hope I have explained this well... Basically I want to scroll down the scroller whether the mouse is over an iFrame or not, but still be able to click on them.

Comment: here is a demo of the scroller if it helps! http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, define a mousewheel event handler inside your iframe.

```
<iframe src="#" onmousewheel=""></iframe>
```